# может ли питон вычислить такое уравнение?

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import*
import math
x = Symbol('x')
print(solve(-0.8722166666*x + 1.301771667 - 2/math.sqrt(math.pi)*math.e**(-x**2)))
[]
```

возникает ошибка NotImplementedError: multiple generators

Comment: sympy похоже что нет. Но накрайняк можно численными методами (т.е. получить численное решение вместо аналитического, какое пытается дать sympy).

Comment: может есть ещё какие то сильные модули?

Comment: scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html